# how to use a persistent named pipe under linux?

Tags: linux, persistent, fifo, mkfifo

Use named pipe some times very convenient, such as `mkfifo file.fifo`.

but the file.fifo is not persistent, if the computer restarted or the writer process crashed, I can get nothing from the pipe. so, are there any methods to let the piped data store in disk rather than memory?

thanks.

Comment: The named pipes use the file-system only as a name space and for basic access control – this may be misleading. They are not real files, the data passing through the pipe is never stored in a file system. If you need something else, then the named pipes are not the tool you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use plain files to store the data. For example, and use a pipe (or similar) to notify that there are new data, for example. You must take care of interprocess locking, of course.

Or you can use "message queues" (see **mqueue.h**). They are persistent in case of process crash, but not if the system is rebooted.

Or you can use a third-party library that implements "persistent message queues", such as [MQTT](https://mqtt.org/) or [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/).

Comment: Please fix the "similar question" link, it is broken currently.

Comment: @grwlf: Thanks for the warning, fixed with a couple alternative links. Having passed 10 years (!) I didn't even remember writing this.

Comment: Files have totally different semantics since you can't atomically free the data you read from the beginning of a file. mqueue fails on reboot, as you noted. MQTT is just a protocol, and has nothing to do with persistence. RabbitMQ is overkill for a single machine and doesn't fsync by default, even for "persistent" messages so it'll happily lose data. Publisher confirms solve this, but at the cost of a massive latency hit on the order of hundreds of ms.